# How can a client receive attributes passed by the server using higher cas-protocol?

Tags: cas

I'm going to upgrade the CAS server from 3.5.x to 5.3.x which uses the CAS protocol 3.0. However, the CAS client still uses the CAS protocal 2.0. The problem is that the client can't receive attributes passed by the server.

The server is built with the [CAS Maven WAR Overlay](https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template) (version:5.3). The client is built with springboot.

Here is some code of the client.

pom.xml:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

The Configuration:

```java
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean validationFilterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    Map<String, String> initParameters = new HashMap<>(2);
    initParameters.put("casServerUrlPrefix", "http://localhost:8080/cas");
    initParameters.put("serverName", "http://localhost:8081");
    registrationBean.setFilter(new Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter());
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    registrationBean.setInitParameters(initParameters);
    registrationBean.setOrder(3);
    return registrationBean;
}
```

The Controller:

```java
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap modelMap) {
        PrintStream out = System.out;
        AttributePrincipal principal = (AttributePrincipal) request.getUserPrincipal();
        if (principal != null) {
            modelMap.put("principal", principal);
            final Map attributes = principal.getAttributes(); // empty
            if (attributes != null) {
                out.println("attributes:" + attributes);
                modelMap.put("attributes", attributes);
            }
        }
        return "index";
    }
```

If I change the filter from `Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter` to `Cas30ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter`, it will be ok. But is there any other solutions so that I don't need to upgrade the code of client?

Comment: CAS Server 5.3.x supports both CAS 2 and 3 authentication protocols. If I recall correctly, only CAS 3 authentication protocol supports attributes. CAS client started supporting CAS 2 and 3 authentication protocols since 3.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem! Do some updating with the cas-server.

#### 1. Add maven dependencies.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-core-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-support-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-core-util-api</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

#### 2. Override the class `org.apereo.cas.web.view.Cas20ResponseView` referring to `org.apereo.cas.web.view.Cas30ResponseView`.

```java
package org.apereo.cas.web.view;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apereo.cas.CasProtocolConstants;
import org.apereo.cas.CasViewConstants;
import org.apereo.cas.authentication.AuthenticationAttributeReleasePolicy;
import org.apereo.cas.authentication.AuthenticationServiceSelectionPlan;
import org.apereo.cas.authentication.ProtocolAttributeEncoder;
import org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.Service;
import org.apereo.cas.services.RegisteredService;
import org.apereo.cas.services.ServicesManager;
import org.apereo.cas.services.web.view.AbstractDelegatingCasView;
import org.apereo.cas.util.CollectionUtils;
import org.apereo.cas.validation.CasProtocolAttributesRenderer;
import org.apereo.cas.web.view.attributes.DefaultCas30ProtocolAttributesRenderer;
import org.apereo.cas.web.view.attributes.InlinedCas30ProtocolAttributesRenderer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.View;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * 参照Cas30ResponseView重写Cas20ResponseView，以便能够向protocol2.0的客户端返回属性。
 * 在构造方法中手动设置以下两个属性
 * this.releaseProtocolAttributes = true;
 * this.attributesRenderer = new DefaultCas30ProtocolAttributesRenderer();
 *
 * @author duqian
 * @date 2019/5/3
 */
@Slf4j
public class Cas20ResponseView extends AbstractDelegatingCasView {
    /**
     * The Service selection strategy.
     */
    protected final AuthenticationServiceSelectionPlan authenticationRequestServiceSelectionStrategies;
    private final CasProtocolAttributesRenderer attributesRenderer;
    private final boolean releaseProtocolAttributes;

    public Cas20ResponseView(final boolean successResponse,
                             final ProtocolAttributeEncoder protocolAttributeEncoder,
                             final ServicesManager servicesManager,
                             final String authenticationContextAttribute,
                             final View view,
                             final AuthenticationAttributeReleasePolicy authenticationAttributeReleasePolicy,
                             final AuthenticationServiceSelectionPlan serviceSelectionStrategy) {
        super(successResponse, protocolAttributeEncoder, servicesManager, authenticationContextAttribute, view, authenticationAttributeReleasePolicy);
        this.authenticationRequestServiceSelectionStrategies = serviceSelectionStrategy;
        this.releaseProtocolAttributes = true;
        this.attributesRenderer = new DefaultCas30ProtocolAttributesRenderer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void prepareMergedOutputModel(final Map<String, Object> model, final HttpServletRequest request,
                                            final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        super.putIntoModel(model, CasViewConstants.MODEL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_PRINCIPAL, getPrincipal(model));
        super.putIntoModel(model, CasViewConstants.MODEL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_CHAINED_AUTHENTICATIONS, getChainedAuthentications(model));
        super.putIntoModel(model, CasViewConstants.MODEL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_PRIMARY_AUTHENTICATION, getPrimaryAuthenticationFrom(model));
        LOGGER.debug("Prepared CAS response output model with attribute names [{}]", model.keySet());

        final Service service = authenticationRequestServiceSelectionStrategies.resolveService(getServiceFrom(model));
        final RegisteredService registeredService = this.servicesManager.findServiceBy(service);

        final Map<String, Object> principalAttributes = getCasPrincipalAttributes(model, registeredService);
        final Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>(principalAttributes);

        LOGGER.debug("Processed principal attributes from the output model to be [{}]", principalAttributes.keySet());
        if (this.releaseProtocolAttributes) {
            LOGGER.debug("CAS is configured to release protocol-level attributes. Processing...");
            final Map<String, Object> protocolAttributes = getCasProtocolAuthenticationAttributes(model, registeredService);
            attributes.putAll(protocolAttributes);
            LOGGER.debug("Processed protocol/authentication attributes from the output model to be [{}]", protocolAttributes.keySet());
        }

        decideIfCredentialPasswordShouldBeReleasedAsAttribute(attributes, model, registeredService);
        decideIfProxyGrantingTicketShouldBeReleasedAsAttribute(attributes, model, registeredService);

        LOGGER.debug("Final collection of attributes for the response are [{}].", attributes.keySet());
        putCasResponseAttributesIntoModel(model, attributes, registeredService);
    }

    /**
     * Put cas authentication attributes into model.
     *
     * @param model             the model
     * @param registeredService the registered service
     * @return the cas authentication attributes
     */
    protected Map<String, Object> getCasProtocolAuthenticationAttributes(final Map<String, Object> model,
                                                                         final RegisteredService registeredService) {

        if (!registeredService.getAttributeReleasePolicy().isAuthorizedToReleaseAuthenticationAttributes()) {
            LOGGER.debug("Attribute release policy for service [{}] is configured to never release any attributes", registeredService);
            return new LinkedHashMap<>(0);
        }

        final Map<String, Object> filteredAuthenticationAttributes = authenticationAttributeReleasePolicy
                .getAuthenticationAttributesForRelease(getPrimaryAuthenticationFrom(model));

        filterCasProtocolAttributes(model, filteredAuthenticationAttributes);

        final String contextProvider = getSatisfiedMultifactorAuthenticationProviderId(model);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(contextProvider) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(authenticationContextAttribute)) {
            filteredAuthenticationAttributes.put(this.authenticationContextAttribute, CollectionUtils.wrap(contextProvider));
        }

        return filteredAuthenticationAttributes;
    }

    private void filterCasProtocolAttributes(final Map<String, Object> model, final Map<String, Object> filteredAuthenticationAttributes) {
        filteredAuthenticationAttributes.put(CasProtocolConstants.VALIDATION_CAS_MODEL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_AUTHENTICATION_DATE,
                CollectionUtils.wrap(getAuthenticationDate(model)));
        filteredAuthenticationAttributes.put(CasProtocolConstants.VALIDATION_CAS_MODEL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_FROM_NEW_LOGIN,
                CollectionUtils.wrap(isAssertionBackedByNewLogin(model)));
        filteredAuthenticationAttributes.put(CasProtocolConstants.VALIDATION_REMEMBER_ME_ATTRIBUTE_NAME,
                CollectionUtils.wrap(isRememberMeAuthentication(model)));
    }

    /**
     * Put cas principal attributes into model.
     *
     * @param model             the model
     * @param registeredService the registered service
     * @return the cas principal attributes
     */
    protected Map<String, Object> getCasPrincipalAttributes(final Map<String, Object> model, final RegisteredService registeredService) {
        return super.getPrincipalAttributesAsMultiValuedAttributes(model);
    }

    /**
     * Put cas response attributes into model.
     *
     * @param model             the model
     * @param attributes        the attributes
     * @param registeredService the registered service
     */
    protected void putCasResponseAttributesIntoModel(final Map<String, Object> model,
                                                     final Map<String, Object> attributes,
                                                     final RegisteredService registeredService) {

        LOGGER.debug("Beginning to encode attributes for the response");
        final Map<String, Object> encodedAttributes = this.protocolAttributeEncoder.encodeAttributes(attributes, registeredService);

        LOGGER.debug("Encoded attributes for the response are [{}]", encodedAttributes);
        super.putIntoModel(model, CasProtocolConstants.VALIDATION_CAS_MODEL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_ATTRIBUTES, encodedAttributes);

        final Collection<String> formattedAttributes = this.attributesRenderer.render(encodedAttributes);
        super.putIntoModel(model, CasProtocolConstants.VALIDATION_CAS_MODEL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_FORMATTED_ATTRIBUTES, formattedAttributes);
    }
}
```

#### 3. override the html file: `templates/protocol/2.0/casServiceValidationSuccess.html` referring to `templates/protocol/3.0/casServiceValidationSuccess.html`

```html
<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas'>
    <cas:authenticationSuccess>
        <cas:user th:text="${principal.id}"/>
        <cas:proxyGrantingTicket th:if="${pgtIou}" th:text="${pgtIou}"/>
        <cas:proxies th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(chainedAuthentications)}">
            <cas:proxy th:each="proxy : ${chainedAuthentications}" th:text="${proxy.principal.id}"/>
        </cas:proxies>
        <!--  从protocol3.0复制，向protocol2.0的客户端传递属性 -->
        <cas:attributes th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(formattedAttributes)}">
            <div th:each="attr : ${formattedAttributes}" th:remove="tag">
                <div th:utext="${attr}" th:remove="tag"/>
            </div>
        </cas:attributes>
        <!--  从protocol3.0复制，向protocol2.0的客户端传递属性 end -->
    </cas:authenticationSuccess>
</cas:serviceResponse>
```

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITj5m.png)

referece: https://blog.csdn.net/eric520zenobia/article/details/78105232